# How to get device array pointer from OpenCL buffer?

Tags: cuda, opencl

I want to test CUDNN library with my OpenCL code (it's also executing on nVidia device).

**Can I somehow get device-based array pointer from OpenCL buffer?**

AFAIK, there should be just the same CUDA pointers, suitable for my workaround.

Comment: The one word answer is no, you can't

Comment: For images I've use CL/GL and CUDA/GL interop to move things between CL and CUDA. Same thing might work for buffers.

Comment: And what if I just write a kernel that takes my buffer as `void*` and write the pointer value to an output? Won't it be the desired CUDA pointer?

Comment: I think it might work, since the pointer and the memory it point to is actually valid. But that will be a very very hacked method of doing it!

Comment: GPUs implement a virtual memory space.  There is no guarantee that the virtual address from an OpenCL context would be in any way related to the virtual address space of a CUDA context.  (Interop APIs will perform the necessary mapping, of course, between "spaces").  It would be analogous to pretending that you could take the address of a host allocation in one host process, and pass that address/pointer to another host process, and expect to be able to access the same allocation.  I would not expect it to work.